# How to fix caption in moderncv?

Tags: floats, captions, minipage, moderncv

I'm using moderncv and I want to add a caption to an inserted graphic. I'm currently using this code

```
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{fixed_button_settings.png}
  \captionof{figure}{Some figure}           
\end{minipage}
```

and this is the result

[image: fixed_button_settings.png]

For further notice, this line of code

```
\captionof{figure}{Some figure}
```

results in an error: Package caption Error: No float type 'figure' defined.

I have added this in the main.tex preamble

```
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
```

What should I do to make the caption appear as: "Figur 1: Some figure"? ("Figur" is not a typo, it's Swedish.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem is that class `moderncv` has no floating environment `figure` implemented.  So you have two possibilities:

1. copy all the code needed for `figure` into an own local new class `mymoderncv.cls` or
2. do not use `figure` and make it by your own. You can use `minipage`, and write the heading by your own, because in a cv you need no list of figures, I guess?

A solution for point 2 could be (I used the image from package `mwe`, that must be installed, but must not be loaded):

```
\documentclass[%
  11pt
 ,a4paper
 ,sans
]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
%\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}

% Personal Data
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\title{Resume title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}\mobile{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone{+2~(345)~678~901}
\fax{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@johndoe.com}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\extrainfo{additional information}
\quote{Some quote from a well known person}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a} \\
  Figure 1: heading of figure.
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

with the result:

[image]

Comment: I used your minipage example and went for manual captioning. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Were is the code for `figure`?

Comment: Not writing a short CV. I found code that works here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/375153/89981