# how to integrate floating environments (figure, table) into moderncv?

Tags: floats, moderncv

Whilst [How to fix caption in moderncv?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136509/how-to-fix-caption-in-moderncv) tells us how to get around using the floating environment, for a range of reasons I am particularly interested in integrating the respective code/class for the floating environments into `moderncv`.

- So, where do I find this code?
- And how do I include it in the `moderncv` document?

Comment: Please try to add a minimal working example (MWE).

Comment: Why would you want a float in a CV?

Comment: @cfr for academic CVs, it is often needed and in the [wish list](https://github.com/xdanaux/moderncv/issues/76)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definition of floating environments `figure` and `table` can for example be found in document class `article` and other files, loaded from within `article`.

You can add the code to the preamble of your cv,  for example like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{classic} % casual, classic, banking, oldstyle and fancy
\moderncvcolor{blue} 
%\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} % \rmdefault
%\nopagenumbers{} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm} 
%\settowidth{\hintscolumnwidth}{Jun-Sep, 2011} 
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm} % for the 'classic' style

% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}
\social[twitter]{jdoe}
\social[github]{jdoe}
\extrainfo{additional information}
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{example-image-a}
\quote{Some quote}

\setlength{\footskip}{66pt}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\figurename{Figure}
\newcommand\tablename{Table}
\newcounter{figure}
\renewcommand \thefigure {\@arabic\c@figure}
\def\fps@figure{tbp}
\def\ftype@figure{1}
\def\ext@figure{lof}
\def\fnum@figure{\figurename\nobreakspace\thefigure}
\newenvironment{figure}
               {\@float{figure}}
               {\end@float}
\newenvironment{figure*}
               {\@dblfloat{figure}}
               {\end@dblfloat}
\newcounter{table}
\renewcommand\thetable{\@arabic\c@table}
\def\fps@table{tbp}
\def\ftype@table{2}
\def\ext@table{lot}
\def\fnum@table{\tablename\nobreakspace\thetable}
\newenvironment{table}
               {\@float{table}}
               {\end@float}
\newenvironment{table*}
               {\@dblfloat{table}}
               {\end@dblfloat}
\newlength\abovecaptionskip
\newlength\belowcaptionskip
\setlength\abovecaptionskip{10\p@}
\setlength\belowcaptionskip{0\p@}
\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
  \vskip\abovecaptionskip
  \sbox\@tempboxa{#1: #2}%
  \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize
    #1: #2\par
  \else
    \global \@minipagefalse
    \hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
  \fi
  \vskip\belowcaptionskip}

\newcommand\listoffigures{%
    \section*{\listfigurename}%
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%
              {\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%
    \@starttoc{lof}%
    }
\newcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}
\newcommand\listoftables{%
    \section*{\listtablename}%
      \@mkboth{%
          \MakeUppercase\listtablename}%
         {\MakeUppercase\listtablename}%
    \@starttoc{lot}%
    }
\let\l@table\l@figure
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\begin{figure}%
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-a}%
\caption{test}%
\label{fig:test}%
\end{figure}

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution--3}{City--4}{\textit{Grade}--5}{Description--6}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}

\section{Experience}
\subsection{Vocational}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{General description no longer than 1--2 lines.\newline{}%
Detailed achievements:%
\begin{itemize}%
\item Achievement 1;
\item Achievement 2, with sub-achievements:
  \begin{itemize}%
  \item Sub-achievement (a);
  \item Sub-achievement (b), with sub-sub-achievements (don't do this!);
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Sub-sub-achievement i;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement ii;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement iii;
    \end{itemize}
  \item Sub-achievement (c);
  \end{itemize}
\item Achievement 3.
\end{itemize}}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description line 1\newline{}Description line 2}
\subsection{Miscellaneous}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description}

\section{Languages}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 1}{Skill level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{\textbf{Language} 2}{\textbf{Skill} level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 3}{Skill level}{Comment}

\section{Computer skills}
\cvdoubleitem{category 1}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 4}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 2}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 5}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 3}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 6}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}

\section{Interests}
\cvitem{hobby 1}{Description}
\cvitem{hobby 2}{Description}
\cvitem{hobby 3}{Description}

\section{Extra 1}
\cvlistitem{Item 1}
\cvlistitem{Item 2}
\cvlistitem{Item 3. This item is particularly long and therefore normally spans over several lines. Did you notice the indentation when the line wraps?}

\section{Extra 2}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 1}{Item 4}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 2}{Item 5}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 3}{Item 6. Like item 3 in the single column list before, this item is particularly long to wrap over several lines.}

\section{References}
\begin{cvcolumns}
  \cvcolumn{Category 1}{\begin{itemize}\item Person 1\item Person 2\item Person 3\end{itemize}}
  \cvcolumn{Category 2}{Amongst others:\begin{itemize}\item Person 1, and\item Person 2\end{itemize}(more upon request)}
  \cvcolumn[0.5]{All the rest \& some more}{\textit{That} person, and \textbf{those} also (all available upon request).}
\end{cvcolumns}


\clearpage
%-----       letter       ---------------------------------------------------------
% recipient data
\recipient{Company Recruitment team}{Company, Inc.\\123 somestreet\\some city}
\date{January 01, 1984}
\opening{Dear Sir or Madam,}
\closing{Yours faithfully,}
\enclosure[Attached]{curriculum vit\ae{}}          % use an optional argument to use a string other than "Enclosure", or redefine \enclname
\makelettertitle

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis ullamcorper 
neque sit amet lectus facilisis sed luctus nisl iaculis. Vivamus at neque 
arcu, sed tempor quam. Curabitur pharetra tincidunt tincidunt. Morbi 
volutpat feugiat mauris, quis tempor neque vehicula volutpat. Duis 
tristique justo vel massa fermentum accumsan. Mauris ante elit, feugiat 
vestibulum tempor eget, eleifend ac ipsum. Donec scelerisque lobortis 
ipsum eu vestibulum. Pellentesque vel massa at felis accumsan rhoncus.

Suspendisse commodo, massa eu congue tincidunt, elit mauris pellentesque 
orci, cursus tempor odio nisl euismod augue. Aliquam adipiscing nibh ut 
odio sodales et pulvinar tortor laoreet. Mauris a accumsan ligula. 
Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per 
inceptos himenaeos. Suspendisse vulputate sem vehicula ipsum varius nec 
tempus dui dapibus. Phasellus et est urna, ut auctor erat. Sed tincidunt 
odio id odio aliquam mattis. Donec sapien nulla, feugiat eget adipiscing 
sit amet, lacinia ut dolor. Phasellus tincidunt, leo a fringilla 
consectetur, felis diam aliquam urna, vitae aliquet lectus orci nec 
velit. Vivamus dapibus varius blandit.

Duis sit amet magna ante, at sodales diam. Aenean consectetur porta risus et sagittis. Ut interdum, enim varius pellentesque tincidunt, magna libero sodales tortor, ut fermentum nunc metus a ante. Vivamus odio leo, tincidunt eu luctus ut, sollicitudin sit amet metus. Nunc sed orci lectus. Ut sodales magna sed velit volutpat sit amet pulvinar diam venenatis.

Albert Einstein discovered that $e=mc^2$ in 1905.

\[ e=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \]

\makeletterclosing

\end{document}
```

with the resulting first page:

[image: first resulting page]

But I think you should better use package [`komacv`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/komacv).  It is based on class `scrarticle` which has included floats ...