# Package caption Error: No float type 'noticebox' defined

Tags: captions, subcaption

I took the NIPS 2018 paper template from [here](https://nips.cc/Conferences/2018/PaperInformation/StyleFiles), which I can compile (via `pdflatex`).

However, when I add this package (before `\title`):

```
\usepackage{caption}
```

I get the error:

```
! Package caption Error: No float type 'noticebox' defined.
```

Why? How can I fix this?
I'm using MacOSX with Texlive 2011.

A reduced example (still using the NIPS style file):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nips_2018}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % allow utf-8 input
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % use 8-bit T1 fonts
\usepackage{hyperref}       % hyperlinks
\usepackage{url}            % simple URL typesetting
\usepackage{booktabs}       % professional-quality tables
\usepackage{amsfonts}       % blackboard math symbols
\usepackage{nicefrac}       % compact symbols for 1/2, etc.
\usepackage{microtype}      % microtypography
\usepackage{caption}

\title{Foo}
\author{foo}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

(Maybe [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136509/how-to-fix-caption-in-moderncv) is related. Or [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86603/subcaption-compatibility-with-acm-document-class).)

Adding this additional command (inspired via [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/135907/2272)) solves it, but not sure if that is a good solution, or what it does:

```
\DeclareCaptionType{noticebox}
```

Comment: I downloaded the `.sty` file and the `.tex` template, to which I added `\usepackage{caption}`. I get no error. Please add a minimal example that shows the issue.

Comment: I can reproduce the issue with TeX Live 2010, not with a fully updated TL 2011. Since the last revision of the style file is dated 2018/03/03, old TeX distributions are quite likely unsupported. Is there a reason for not upgrading your MacTeX/TeX Live?

Comment: @egreg Not really. But I was also posting this here in case anyone else stumbles upon this problem, because there was no single Google hit for this error.

Comment: BTW: This incompatibility was fixed (by me) on 2010/10/26, i.e. 8 years ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should upgrade your TeX Live distribution.

There is a way to solve the issue, anyhow.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nips_2018}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % allow utf-8 input
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % use 8-bit T1 fonts
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}       % professional-quality tables
\usepackage{amsfonts}       % blackboard math symbols
\usepackage{nicefrac}       % compact symbols for 1/2, etc.
\usepackage{microtype}      % microtypography
\usepackage{hyperref}       % hyperlinks

\makeatletter
\@ifpackagelater{caption}{2011/01/01}
  {}
  {\usepackage{float}\newfloat{noticebox}{htbp}{.nb}}
\makeatother

\title{Foo}
\author{foo}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

I also loaded `hyperref` last, which is its proper position, notwithstanding what the authors of `nips2018` think.

With the `\@ifpackagelater` instruction we only do the patch if `caption` is pre-2011.